# How to get the value of an input field inside the table td using javascript selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this line of code where it gets the value inside the td part of the table.

```
document.getElementById("supplierID").value = $tr.find('td:eq(0)').html();
```

The above code successfully get the data inside the td part of the table. E.g

```
<td>{{ $val->fname }}</td>
```

However, if the td has input field inside it

```
<td><input type='checkbox'style='width:30px; height:20px;' class='radio_check_all prod-id-checkbox' id='prod-id-checkbox' value="{{ $val->id }}"></td>
```

it returns the markup code of an input field using the code shown above. It doesn't get the right value. How would I do it? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `$tr.find('td:eq(0) input').val();`

Comment: I'm sorry. I made an update on it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should work

check this

```js
$(function(){
  var table=$("table");
  alert(table.find('tr td:eq(0) input').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' style='width:30px; height:20px;' class='radio_check_all prod-id-checkbox' id='prod-id-checkbox' value="{{ $val->id }}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

So what you are saying is, if the element inside the table cell is an input, return the value. Otherwise if it is just text, return the text.

```
var $el = $('tr td:eq(0)'),
testEl = $el.has('input').length;

document.getElementById("supplierID").value = testEl ? $('input', $el).val() : $el.text();
```